# How can i use max(id) as a search condition in sql ce?

Tags: c#, mysql

I am trying to make a game. This game contains a database. Here is part of my code:

```
        string ConnectionString = @"Data Source =" + Application.StartupPath + @"\mydb.sdf";
        SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source="Application.StartupPath + @"\mydb.sdf");

        var sql= @"SELECT Points FROM Userrecords WHERE ID = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM Userrecords) AND Username = @UserName ";
        SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand(sql, con);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserName", LoginInfo.UserID);

        con.Open();

        var ob = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
               // Pointlbl.Text = (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

        //cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
```

The problem is that i do not know how to form that SELECT query properly, so the code always ends up throwing a NULL exception on this line : `var ob = cmd.ExecuteScalar();`

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException' occurred in System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll

What is the most correct way to form the select query?

Comment: What is the exact exception you get? Can we see the stack trace and message?

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException' occurred in System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll That's the exception, and when i hover over the ob value, it says that it's value is NULL.

Comment: Yes, i am sure that the .sdf file is in the same folder as the executable.

Comment: That was a mistake on my part.  Ignore that comment lol.

Comment: However, why are you trying to match both the max ID and the username?  If you want the max ID then use that, otherwise use UserName, if you use both you will only get a result if you pass the username of the person who has the max ID.

Comment: I need both because the ID (it is a session ID actually) indicates the last time that the person played the game (bigger ID = most recent time the person played the game), so that i can use the most recent points and redirect the user to the respective level.

Comment: Then you should use scaisEdge's answer, since it will give you that.

Comment: I tried it, but it gives the same exception unfortunately...

Comment: The exception occurs at `var ob = cmd.ExecuteScalar()` correct?

Comment: Yes. That's exactly where it occurs.

Comment: The SqlCeException should have a Message property that gives a description of what the problem is.  Can you try and see what it is?  That most likely contains information that is needed to determine the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's all that the Message shows. And the exception details don't help either...

Comment: Wow, what a useless error...

Comment: LoginInfo and Name are both not null correct?

Comment: Yes. I am sure that those are not NULL.

Comment: Is it possible that Userrecords doesn't exist at this point?  What if this is the first time the user has played the game?

Comment: This query is used on the second level and up, the first level begins from zero points, so this query is not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If scaisEdge's query does not work, perhaps try the following:

```
SELECT TOP 1 Points
FROM Userrecords
WHERE Username = @UserName
ORDER BY ID DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

could be that your and clause must be  placed  inside the subselect

```
SELECT Points 
FROM Userrecords 
WHERE ID = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM Userrecords
          AND Username = @UserName )
```

otherwise the could be not match and not return proper values